# Stack overflow error in main instantiating two objects?

Tags: java

Hello I'm still new to Java and OOP and am having issues trying to get my code to compile. I understand the issue with my code is the instantiation of the same object twice however I'm not sure how I can work around that to compile my code.

```
package week2;

import java.util.*

public class aBug {

    aBug theBug = new aBug();
    String Inspecies, Inname;
    int Inx, Iny, Inenergy, Inid;
    char Insymbol;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    aWorld newWorld = new aWorld();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aBug theBug = new aBug();


        theBug.mainMenu();

    }

    public void mainMenu() {

        int choice;
        do {

            System.out.print("1\t Create bug\n");
            System.out.print("2\t Enter world\n");
            System.out.print("3\t Quit\n");
            choice = scan.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                bugInit();
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println();
                newWorld.mapInit(theBug.Inx, theBug.Iny, theBug.Insymbol);
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }
        } while (choice != 3);
    }

    public void bugInit() {
        String species, name;
        int x, y, energy, id;
        char symbol;



        System.out.print("Species: ");
        species = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("X position: ");
        x = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Y position: ");
        y = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Energy: ");
        energy = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("ID: ");
        id = scan.nextInt();

        theBug.Insymbol = 'b';
        theBug.Inspecies = species;
        theBug.Inname = name;
        theBug.Inx = x;
        theBug.Iny = y;
        theBug.Inenergy = energy;
        theBug.Inid = id;

        System.out
                .format("\nThe bug is of the species %s, called %s, "
                        + "with positions %d & %d, with energy amount: %d, and %d as it's id number\n\n",
                        theBug.Inspecies, theBug.Inname, theBug.Inx, theBug.Iny,
                        theBug.Inenergy, theBug.Inid);

    }


}
```

Comment: Post the stack of errors you got.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at week2.aBug.<init>(aBug.java:6)
 at week2.aBug.<init>(aBug.java:6)
 at week2.aBug.<init>(aBug.java:6)
 at week2.aBug.<init>(aBug.java:6)
 at week2.aBug.<init>(aBug.java:6)
 at week2.aBug.<init>(aBug.java:6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor you have:

```
public class aBug {
    aBug theBug = new aBug();
...
}
```

So while creating an instance of `aBug` (for example in your `main`) you call `new aBug()`, which calls the constructor again recurrently with out end overflowing the stack.

I am not sure why do you think you need to create an instance of the object within itself. So it's hard to give any hints. If I guess correctly, you merged the idea of `aBug` and "main program" in one class. You should split it and put `aBug` internal stuff in its own class.